# Cancel an async task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

For example I have something like this. When I am clicking on first button it start's async process and then I am clicking second button it start's second process. But I need only one process to work after clicking on each button. How can I cancel other process?

```
namespace WpfApplication55
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        TestCombo TC = new TestCombo();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = TC;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TC.Begin(60);
        }

        private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TC.Begin(120);
        }
    }

    public class TestCombo:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int someData;
        public int SomeData 
        {
            get { return someData; }
            set { someData = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SomeData"); }
        }

        public void StartCount(int input)
        {
            SomeData = input;
            while (input>0)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                input -= 1;
                SomeData = input;
            }
        }

        public void Begin(int input)
        {   
            Action<int> Start = new Action<int>(StartCount);
            IAsyncResult result = Start.BeginInvoke(input, null, null);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged (string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why are you using `Action.BeginInvoke` and a class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead of a simple `await Task.Run`? 2) Do you want to *cancel* the pending operation and start a new one, or prevent the second one from starting when there's already one running? 3) Do you have control over what's in the "asynchronous operation" you're running? Can you add cancellation checks?

Comment: 1) I am using .net 4., using INotifyPropertyChanged  because it's wpf.
2) I want to cancel running async proces and start new one(which was clicked).
3) i have label with binding to <Label Height="52" Content="{Binding SomeData}"></Label>

Comment: You can use `Start.EndInvoke(result);` if you define Start globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you want the while condition in StartCount to work but as long as you evaluating the new CancellationToken you should be good to cancel. Remember the Thread.Sleep won't cancel while its sleeping. So you may have up to a 1s delay.

```
public void StartCount(int input, CancellationToken token)
{
    SomeData = input;
    while (input > 0 && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        input -= 1;
        SomeData = input;
    }
}

IAsyncResult process;
public void Begin(int input)
{
    if (process != null && !process.IsCompleted)
        ((CancellationTokenSource)process.AsyncState).Cancel();
    Action<int, CancellationToken> Start = new Action<int, CancellationToken>(StartCount);
    var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    process = Start.BeginInvoke(input,cancelSource.Token, null, cancelSource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this.

Here's your class:

```
public class TestCombo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int someData;
    public int SomeData 
    {
        get { return someData; }
        set { someData = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SomeData"); }
    }

    private SingleAssignmentDisposable _subscription = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();

    public void Begin(int input)
    {
        _subscription.Disposable =
            Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
                .Select(x => input - (int)x)
                .Take(input)
                .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                .Subscribe(x => this.SomeData = x);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged (string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

The two key parts to this solution is first the observable query subscription which does all of the timing, computes the value to assign to `SomeData` and marshals the assignment to the UI thread.

The second is the `SingleAssignmentDisposable`. When you assign a new `IDisposable` to its `Disposable` property it will dispose any previously assigned `IDisposable`.

The disposing cancels the previous subscription.

Just NuGet "Rx-WPF" to get the WPF bits for Rx.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
namespace WpfApplication55
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        TestCombo TC = new TestCombo();
        CancellationTokenSource cts;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = TC;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cts != null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
            }

            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            await TC.DoAsync(60, cts.Token);
        }

        private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cts != null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
            }

            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            await TC.DoAsync(120, cts.Token);
        }
    }

    public class TestCombo:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int someData;
        public int SomeData 
        {
            get { return someData; }
            set { someData = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SomeData"); }
        }

        public void StartCount(int input)
        {
            SomeData = input;
            while (input>0)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                input -= 1;
                SomeData = input;
            }
        }

        public Task DoAsync(int input, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {   
            return Task.Run(StartCount, cancellationToken);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged (string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using class CancellationTokenSource;
See code below-

```
CancellationTokenSource   ctstask = new CancellationTokenSource();
ctstask.Cancel();//This line should be called from 2nd button click.
```

Comment: This will do nothing without adding code which checks on the token.

Comment: Ofcourse, @YuvalItzchakov, was implied. The above 2-line code was only a hint-> not full code...